Is there a natural and polite way to answer to someone putting themselves down?
I've been talking to someone online for a few days, so I don't know them that well but we're friendly enough. They've told me that 「スポーツはちょっと苦手　:(」(speaking about themselves) and in my language we tend not to ignore such comments, but rather offer polite (or genuine) words of encouragement. I wonder if in this case it might actually be rude to emphasise it by replying to it?
I feel like in Japanese, you wouldn't typically talk yourself up, but is there a way for me to kindly acknowledge their comment, without necessarily denying it since I've got no idea whether it is true or not? Maybe convey that they're cool in other ways that being good at sports?
Thank you!

What is the context? Did you invite them to some activity and this is how they responded?

Hi, no it really wasn't anything more than a passing comment, I've replied to them since but my starting question was : is there's a common way to reply when, for example, someone tells you (unprompted) something like "I suck at this", would you answer with anything like "no, I'm sure you don't suck" or "you don't have to talk badly about yourself"! or would you just let it go and ignore it? It's really just out of curiosity, thank your for your time :D

I think this is ultimately more about how to keep conversations pleasant than about the Japanese language. You might want to push back, change the topic, or encourage - it's your choice.
That said, something along the lines of

そうなんですか。意外です。

will be relatively neutral. It allows you to push back on what might be exaggerated self deprecation a little bit, without sounding like you know more than you do. You are surprised, but you basically trust what they say. That makes it a safe response regardless of whether they are genuine or exaggerating.
If you want to flatter, you could say 御謙遜を. This implies "I don't believe that", and it can go awkward if they are completely genuine, though.
If it's only a small part of what's being said, and there is something else to respond to, I think it's fine to let it slide, too.
I personally wouldn't expect to hear an encouragement in this case, but I wouldn't take that in a bad way, either.
